# Explain the MvxAttributeViewPresenter.Show Change in 8.0.1

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross

In MvvmCross.Presenters.MvxAttributeViewPresenter the Show Methods seems to break from previous versions. I currently had to override the default presenter show with the following which is the same as 6.4.2.

```
public override Task<bool> Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    var tmp = GetPresentationAttributeAction(request, out MvxBasePresentationAttribute attribute).ShowAction.Invoke(attribute.ViewType, attribute, request);
    return tmp;
}
```

The original code is as follows but I don't understand why it was changed.

```
public override Task<bool> Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    var attributeAction = GetPresentationAttributeAction(request, out MvxBasePresentationAttribute attribute);

    if (attributeAction.ShowAction != null && attribute.ViewType != null)
        return attributeAction.ShowAction.Invoke(attribute.ViewType, attribute, request);

    return Task.FromResult(false);
 }
```

Comment: The new show method does not make the assumption that the ShowAction and ViewType properties in the presentation attribute are always non-null. In other words, the behavior is exactly the same, but the implementation is less fragile. Your app wont crash and instead just do nothing when trying to process a presentation attribute that doesn't have those fields defined.